# Media Player Classic with latest K-Lite Codec chokes on FLV

Tags: flash, vlc-media-player, media-player, flv, video-codecs

I have FLV files that I want to play with [Media Player Classic](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/). Whenever I seek using the navigation bar the whole video stops. When I play it again, I receive the last still image while the audio continues.

I know others would suggest VLC. But, what I'm up to is the audio boost of Media Player Classic on the audio switcher settings.

Comment: flv is not a codec, just a container

Comment: VLC has volume boost as well, I am not as familiar with media center classic, so you may be talking about something different. VLC volume control goes to 200%, but I'd like it better if if went to 11

Comment: @vtest yes, but he never said it was a codec...he was talking about klite codec pack...i suggested re-encoding the flv file because some sites do crazy to break seeking with the container structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really an answer. So I used VLC and bought louder speakers.